# Вывести картинку в браузере из поля bytea базы Postgresql

Tags: php, javascript, html5, postgresql

Есть картинка : *abc.jpg*

```
-- Вношу её в базу Postgresql :    

INSERT INTO tbl (picture) VALUES (pg_read_binary_file('data\abc.jpg'));
```

Вижу, что данные 'зашли' и имеют длину :

```
SELECT length(picture) as size_in_bytes FROM tbl; -- 414590
```

---

На сервере PHP получаю данные из базы для отправки клиенту в браузер :

```
      $se = $conn->query("SELECT encode(picture, 'hex') as \"1\" FROM tbl WHERE id_t = 44;");         

      $data = $se->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // получаю объект $data;
```

Отправляю :

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

---

На клиенте :

```
alert(xhr.responseText); // показал, что данные пришли;
```

Подготавливаю для вывода в браузер :

```
var picture = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
alert(picture[0][1]);                       // <-- вижу данные : ffd8ffe116da4578696...;

document.getElementById('sss').src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + picture[0][1];
```

Но в браузер картинка не выводится.
Например, сюда :

```
<img id="sss" src="" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
```

Искал причину, пробовал encode/decode a base64, - но так и не получил результат.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать правильно? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось так :

---

1. если хранить данные в базе в поле типа bytea, то

   SELECT encode(picture, 'base64') as ...
2. если хранить в поле типа text, то

   SELECT encode(picture::bytea, 'base64') as ...

   ---

Ошибка была, когда с полем text делал *encode(picture, 'base64')*, - так не работает.